# How Can I clone a database in Microsoft SQL server using PHP?

Tags: sql-server, php

I am creating a portal where user can create the b2c or b2b store itself, so I need to clone the sample database to perform the task. It's not looking simple to clone the database in MSSQL. Please help if someone knows the solution.

```
$sql = "RESTORE DATABASE test2 FROM DISK=N'/var/pathto/TEST.bak'
        WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY
        , MOVE 'TEST' TO '/var/pathto/TEST.mdf'
        , MOVE 'TEST_log' TO '/var/pathto/TEST_log.ldf'";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    exit('executedd.');
}
```

What's wrong with my script?

/**************************************/

After hours of research below script is working but still showing restoring in SQL Server Management studio, check the attached screenshot.

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE test9";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    //echo ('executedd.');
}

$sql = "USE test9";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    //echo ('executedd.');
}

$sql = "BACKUP DATABASE test9 TO DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/data/test9.bak'";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    //echo ('executedd.');
}

$sql = "RESTORE DATABASE test9 FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/data/test4.bak'
        WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY
        , MOVE 'test4' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/test9.mdf'
        , MOVE 'test4_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/test9_log.ldf'";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    //echo ('executedd.');
}
exit;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to take and then restore a backup of the database.  If your sample database is fairly static then I suggest making a gold standard backup and using that.  If it's under constant modification then taking a backup and then restoring it on the spot should be sufficient.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Sample] TO DISK=N'<path to file>'

RESTORE DATABASE [TargetName] FROM DISK=N'<path to file>'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY
, MOVE 'file1' TO '<new path for data file>'
, MOVE 'log1' TO '<new path for log file>'
```

Just make those commands dynamic and grant whatever user you are using for this db_creator and db_backupoperator

However, this command assumes that [TargetName] doesn't already exist.  You can check for the existence of a database by querying sys.databases.  If you need to override an existing database, then you need to kick everyone out before starting the restore.

Both of the commands above should be run from [master] to avoid conflicts.

This command will set a database to single_user mode, which will kick everyone out.  However, the first connection to it will take the only allowed connection, so you should run this and then immediately run the restore command, preferably in the same transaction.

```
ALTER DATABASE [TargetName]
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: I added some additional information to the answer.  I assumed that you would check for duplicate databases before running the commands.  Creating a new database shouldn't cause any issues, but if the target already exists then you need to kick everyone out first.

Comment: You will probably need a final step in there to recreate any database roles (if required) and then remap them to the appropriate SQL login(s)

Comment: Your move commands, do those files already exist (they shouldn't)?  Does the database already exist (you need to be in the context of master and no one else connected to the target database for the restore to work [including object explorer and other SSMS windows you may have open])?  As for users, if it's on the same server then any permissions that were on the source database will work just fine.

Comment: Wait a bit, it might be running recovery. You might find information in the errorlog

Comment: and make sure to refresh your view in SSMS, it's not dynamic and won't automatically adjust to show the new state.   Just right click on the database and select refresh.  Or check it's status from sys.databaes.

Comment: @JonathanFite: please check my answer below and guide me if something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found a below solution to clone any database and its really works for me. Hope it will be helpful for others as well.

```
/*create table */
$newDatabase        =   'store_live2';
$copyFromDatabase   =   'import_test';

$sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$newDatabase;
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    $error = sqlsrv_errors();
    echo $error[0]['SQLSTATE'].': '.$error[0]['message'];
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}

$sql = "USE ".$newDatabase;
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    //echo ('executedd.');
}

/* select database from where we wants to copy the data */
$sql    =   "SELECT TABLE_NAME 
            FROM ".$copyFromDatabase.".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
        $arrSql = [];
    while( $_tables = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        /* to copy only structure use WHERE 1=2 and if want structure with data then remove WHERE 1=2 */
        $_arrSql[]  =   "SELECT *
                        INTO ".$_newStoreDatabase.".dbo.".$_tables['TABLE_NAME']."
                        FROM ".$_copyFromDatabase.".dbo.".$_tables['TABLE_NAME']."  WHERE 1=2";
    }
    
    /* run all queries at once */
    $sql = implode($arrSql, ';');
    $stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if($stmt === false) 
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
        die(); 
    }else
    {
        echo ('executed.<br>');
    }
}

$connOptions = array("Database"=>$newDatabase, "UID"=>'test', "PWD"=>'test123'); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connOptions);
if($conn){
    echo "<br><br>Database <b>{$newDatabase}</b> has been connected.";
}else{
    exit('Database Not Connected!');
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: If it works for you then that's great!  You have the issue of permissions, as a backup would carry permissions forward, but this method will not (may be a feature).  However, this is likely to be extremely resource intensive unless your source database is very small.  This will cause large transaction log usage and tie up the source database while you are copying the data.  Additionally, it uses the INFORMATION_SCHEMA which is a deprecated feature.  sys.tables is the way to go.

Comment: Oh, also no indexes, views, stored procedures, functions, etc. will be carried forward.

Comment: @JonathanFite: what if I will close the connection and clear useless data logs?

Comment: Even if the database is in simple recovery model, each table load will need to fit in the transaction log until it can be committed.  So if you have a 20GB table then you need 20GB in the log file and in the data file (assuming you load it this way).

Comment: @JonathanFite: So you are trying to say that is not a good approach to clone a database, the approach I was trying previously was good once. Correct?

Comment: @JonathanFite: I just get to know that it's not creating indexes :( and the restore query you told me above is working fine in SSMS but showing database as restoring when I am running the same query via PHP. Do you any clue?

Comment: @JonathanFite: Finally, I made it but thanks for your support.

Comment: @SeniorPHPDeveloper What is `$_tables['TABLE_NAME']` is throwing error as undefined.

Comment: @Ruprit, it's a typo error, please chagne $table to $_tables in while loop variable assignment

Answer (score 0):

Now, I break the nutshell and developed a script which can clone a database dynamically with indexes, constraints and all other configurations. Its was quite hard but I made it.

```
$sql = "USE [master]; BACKUP DATABASE test TO DISK='/var/pathtodir/test.bak'";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    //echo ('executedd.');
}

$sql = "USE [master]; RESTORE DATABASE test5 FROM DISK='/var/pathtodir/test.bak'
        WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY
        , MOVE 'test' TO '/var/pathtodir/test5.mdf'
        , MOVE 'test_log' TO '/var/pathtodir/test5_log.ldf'";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    //echo ('executedd.');
}

$sql = "USE test5";
$stmt   =   sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); echo '</pre>'; 
    die(); 
}else
{
    echo ('executedd.');
}
```